# Determining the target address in a heap overflow

Tags: attacks, buffer-overflow, c, heap-overflow

For a heap overflow to occur and arbitrary code to be executed, the function `free()` performs the step :

`hdr->next->next->prev = hdr->next->prev`

I understand that the address of `hdr->next->next->prev` is calculated as `hdr->next->next + 4` . Pretty clear.

Now, this value will be overwritten by the address hdr->next->prev which is controlled by the attacker and which contains the shell code possibly in the heap itself(assuming it is executable)

The target address i.e. the value in `hdr->next->next` in a vanilla heap overflow should be the address in the stack that stores the return address after `free()` has completed its job.

Q1. How does an attacker determine the *Exact* address of the return pointer of `free()` on the stack ?

Q2. The whole reason this occurs is because the pointer adds 4 to the `hdr->next->next` value to write the `prev` pointer. Has this been fixed or is it still one of the reasons for current heap overflows. (The reason why I'm asking this is, I am aware of other heap exploitations such as double free and so on, just want to make sure if the primitive reason was fixed)

Answer (score 2):

A great, in-depth resource on a buffer overflow attack is the [Smashing the Stack](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~read/bofs.html) tutorial by Aleph One.  While stack overflow and heap overflow are subtly different, the techniques are similar/related.

Felix "FX" Lindner writes an excellent [article](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/A-Heap-of-Risk-747161.html) (2006) on The H Security which describes your exploit in depth. Condensed version below; strongly recommend the full article for clarity.

In answer to Q1, determining the exact address pointer for the stack is the catch. Often - because of stack allocation, varying program and data length, etc, you can't detect the exact position without significant knowledge of the memory layout .  Instead, a common technique is to pad a series of instructions around the payload code in an attempt to "hit" the stack pointer.  A series of NOP instructions are written before the payload code so that "if" the SP is caught in the resulting buffer overflow, the SP will advance until it runs your payload. For the case where the SP is "after" your payload code, you might write a series of JMP instructions all pointing to the head of the payload. (See the tutorial; Aleph covers this process in detail).

The goal of this heap overflow is to corrupt heap record metadata just prior to the 'write' operation implicit in the assignment of `hdr->next->prev` to `hdr->next->next->prev`. With the linked list corrupted, it is possible to overwrite the return address used by the end of `free` on the stack.

In answer to Q2, I'll assume you're asking about the GNU Libc implementation of `free()`.  Other implementations will likely have different code.  Multiple sanity checks now exist to prevent invalid sized objects and double free, etc. (See the `_int_free()` and related functions in [Git](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=malloc/malloc.c;hb=HEAD)). This is not to say (definitively) the vector is impossible through other means, but it is more difficult now.

A third (draft?) source of information on this subject is a whitepaper by Justin Ferguson: [Understanding the Heap by Breaking It](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-07/Ferguson/Whitepaper/bh-usa-07-ferguson-WP.pdf)